# WPF - Turn on/off keyboard from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

There's a custom touchscreen keyboard in my app built according to this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32568/A-Touch-Screen-Keyboard-Control-in-WPF.
I also have a ResourceDictionary containing all styles and templates. In the TextBox style, I can set the keyboard ON/OFF:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">     
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="k:TouchScreenKeyboard.TouchScreenKeyboard" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

I would like the user to be able to turn it on or off from the UI, but can't figure out how to reach this property from code behind. I would like to make it without naming the style, since it's pretty commonly used throughout the app. 
I tried this, but (no surprise) get ArgumentNotFoundException:

```
Style s = Application.Current.FindResource("defTextBox") as Style;
s.RegisterName("Keyboard.TouchScreenKeyboard.TouchScreenKeyBoard",false);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Changing the definition of the Style once it has already been applied to the TextBoxes has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud be able to set the `TouchScreenKeyboard` attached property for an individual `TextBox` like this:

```
TouchScreenKeyboard.SetTouchScreenKeyboard(textBox1, false);
```

Changing the defintion of the implicit `Style` itself after it has already been applied to all `TextBox` elements doesn't make much sense though. You should define the default value in XAML and then change the value for individual `TextBoxes` dynamically at runtime if you need to.